# Automate selection of BIC-minimizing ARIMA(1,0,X) model

Tags: time-series, r, modeling, arima

I want to estimate an ARIMA(1,0,X) model. The MA(X) in the model is selected to minimize BIC. I have the following code employing the function `auto.arima` from "forecast" package in R:

```
 auto.arima(logret$appl, d=0, max.p=1, max.q=10,
 max.order=NA, max.d=0,start.p=1, start.q=0,
 stationary=FALSE, seasonal=FALSE,
 ic=c("bic"), stepwise=TRUE, trace=TRUE,
 allowdrift=TRUE, allowmean=TRUE, lambda=NULL, parallel=FALSE, num.cores=NULL)
```

The following is the result of the above code

```
 ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean : -6592.886
 ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean : -6597.561
 ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean : -6592.886
 ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean : -6592.48
 ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean     : -6604.679
 ARIMA(1,0,1) with non-zero mean : -6586.55

Best model: ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Series: logreturns$REL.CP 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
      intercept
          0e+00
s.e.      5e-04

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0002818:  log likelihood=3305.9
AIC=-6607.81   AICc=-6607.8   BIC=-6597.56
```

My problem requires to keep `AR(1)` and `d=0` in all the models where I test MA lags. Is there a way to fix AR lags? What I really want is MA(1) coefficient out of this arima(1,0, X) model. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually. Let `x` be the data series. The code below considers all moving-average lag orders between `0` and `max.q` and prints out the BIC-minimizing lag order and the corresponding estimated model:

```
m=list() # I will save estimated ARIMA(1,0,q) models here
BIC=c()  # I will save the corresponding BIC values here
max.q=10 # the maximum MA order you want to consider
n=length(x)
for(q in 0:max.q){
 m[[q+1]]=arima(x,order=c(1,0,q),method="ML")
 BIC[q+1]=AIC(m[[q+1]],k=log(n))
}
print(paste("BIC-optimal MA order is",which.min(BIC)-1)) # info message
print(m[[which.min(BIC)]]) # print the estimated BIC-optimal model
```

**Edit:**

To respond to a request in the comments, I am including a function that returns the estimated MA1 coefficient:

```
MA1fromARIMA10q=function(x,max.q=10,...){
 # x is a data vector (a time series)
 # max.q is the maximum MA order to be considered
 m=list() # I will save estimated ARIMA(1,0,q) models here
 BIC=c()  # I will save the corresponding BIC values here
 n=length(x)
 for(q in 0:max.q){
  m[[q+1]]=arima(x,order=c(1,0,q),...)
  BIC[q+1]=AIC(m[[q+1]],k=log(n))
 }
 q=which.min(BIC)-1
 if(q>0) MA1=coef(m[[q+1]])[2] else(MA1=NA) # if MA order is 0, assign NA
 return(MA1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Richard Hardy. Would you please form a single function with this loop you have written that when applied to time series "x" gives the ma[1] coefficient for the arima(1, 0, x).

Comment: Once you have run the function and assigned its result to variable `z`, the ma1 coefficient can now be extracted as `z$MAcoeffs[1]` or `z[[3]][1]`.

Comment: Thanks again @@Richard Hardy. I needed something like this. SuperFun = function(x)  coef(arima(x, order=c(1,0,q), method = "ML")))["ma1"] . mumbo= aggregate(cbind(pop) ~   day + country , idf, FUN = SuperFun) where q comes from  BIC-optimal model. Your function is fine I just make out how to use it as a sub function in the above code

Comment: If you are already programming in R, I suppose you should have no difficulty in tailoring my function to your needs.

Comment: yes but still at beginner level. Actually,  I can't understand how to find best arima(1, 0, x) and call the ma(1) coefficient simultaneously .  Kindly bear with me.

Comment: Is it better now? The function selects an optimal ARIMA(1,0,q) model and just returns the MA1 coefficient directly.

Comment: Suppose I need ar(1) from this model. where do I need to change the code. And why there is k=log(n)

Comment: If you want AR1 coefficient, replace `[2]` with `[1]` in `MA1=coef(m[[q+1]])[2]` (then the function name and the variable name `MA1` in the function will not make sense, but that is not so important.)

Comment: Brilliant @Richard Hardy. you have helped me a lot. Thanks for your time and effort. I have been stuck with this for almost 3 months. After all this coding, the console shows: non-stationary AR part from CSS. Secondly please have a look at my other question to which you have commented.

Comment: Try supplying the argument `method=ML` when calling my function. Also, you could try function `Arima` from "forecast" package instead of the standard `arima` function. `Arima` is a slightly more robust version of `arima`. Just replace `arima` with `Arima` in the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38811/discussion-between-polar-bear-and-richard-hardy).

Comment: how to sum the MA coefficients of the best BIC minimizing model?

Comment: @PolarBear, What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Sum of All MA coefficients in ARIMA(1,0,x) model which has minimum BIC.

Comment: `$coef` extracts the coefficients from a fitted model. E.g. `m$coef` will extract the coefficients from fitted model `m`. Then just select the MA ones like `m$coef[(1+1):(1+x)]` and sum them using the `sum` function: `sum(m$coef[(1:1):(1+x)])`.

Comment: MA.ARIMA10q=function(x,max.q=10,...){
  # x is a data vector (a time series)
  # max.q is the maximum MA order to be considered
  m=list() # I will save estimated ARIMA(1,0,q) models here
  BIC=c()  # I will save the corresponding BIC values here
  n=length(x)
  for(q in 0:max.q){
    m[[q+1]]=Arima(x,order=c(1,0,q),method = "ML")
    BIC[q+1]=AIC(m[[q+1]],k=log(n))
  }
  q=which.min(BIC)-1
if(q=0) Summ=0 else(for i in 1:q){
MAC[i]= coef(m[[q+1]])[i+1]
}
SUM= sum(MAC)
return(SUM)
}
?

Comment: Look, there is a code review stack exchange, I think. Code review questions should be more on topic there than here.

Comment: Right. But I thought that since you helped me in past you might also help me this time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46853/discussion-between-richard-hardy-and-polar-bear).

Comment: How does Arima() from forecast package treat NA values in the series?

Comment: @PolarBear, I do not know, really. I have not encountered this question before, so I would just try googling the answer. And then my marginal contribution would be minimal as anyone can google.

Comment: Thanks for response, Richard. I have been googling for a while but to no use.

Comment: @PolarBear, Have you tried any examples? Have you looked at the code of `arima` (since `Arima` is little more than a wrapper for `arima`)?

Comment: I have been trying to solve this error for some time: Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0 , Would you help how to resolve it?

Comment: @PolarBear, Difficult to tell... Maybe ask on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Richard, I have realized that it is due to missing values for ML method as when I do x<-na.omit(x), it works.  But I am really puzzled why it works for some missing value series while for some not?

Comment: @PolarBear, really, this is not the place to discuss it. If I knew a good 5-word answer, I would give it. But I don't. And then this is totally unrelated to the post above. So better start a new thread on Stack Overflow or somewhere else and get a proper answer there. That's my humble opinion.